# How to refresh an image display in C# for a ribbon in an Excel2010 Add-in?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, add-in, ribbon, excel-2010

I have a dropDown ribon control which has an image. Each time I click on a button (called Generate) next to this dropDown control I would like to rotate the image.
There is no real goal except training.

I am currently using this code to do it :

```
private void buttonGenerate_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    dropDown1.Image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    dropDown1.Visible = false;
    dropDown1.Visible = true;
}
```

It works but I'm looking for a "cleaner" way to refresh the image. Setting Visible to false and then to true does not seem to be the best way. I have been trying some properties but none has been able to refresh the image display so far.

I guess I'm missing the right property to do it.

Thanks for you help,

Corentin

Comment: Usually a method Invalidate(), Refresh(), Repaint() or Update() are the usual candidates.

Comment: Thank you for your help but sadly I did not find any of those.

Comment: Strange, whats the full class name of dropDown1?